# What is output tensor of Max Pooling 2D Layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, max-pooling

I was trying to understand some basics about the tensorflow 
and I got stuck while reading documentation for max pooling 2D layer: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#pooling_layer_1

This is how max_pooling2d is specified:

`pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)`

where `conv1` has a tensor with shape `[batch_size, image_width, image_height, channels]`, concretely in this case it's `[batch_size, 28, 28, 32]`.

So our input is a tensor with shape: `[batch_size, 28, 28, 32]`.

My understanding of a max pooling 2D layer is that it will apply a filter of size `pool_size` (2x2 in this case) and moving sliding window by `stride` (also 2x2). This means that both `width` and `height` of the image will be halfed, i.e. we will end up with 14x14 pixels per channel (32 channels in total), meaning our output is a tensor with shape: `[batch_size, 14, 14, 32]`.

However, according to the above link, the shape of the output tensor is `[batch_size, 14, 14, 1]`:

```
Our output tensor produced by max_pooling2d() (pool1) has a shape of 
[batch_size, 14, 14, 1]: the 2x2 filter reduces width and height by 50%.
```

What am I missing here?

How was 32 converted to 1?

They apply the same logic later here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#convolutional_layer_2_and_pooling_layer_2

but this time it's correct, i.e. `[batch_size, 14, 14, 64]` becomes `[batch_size, 7, 7, 64]` (number of channels is the same).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use 2x2 max pool with strides=2x2 will reduce data to a half, and the output depth will not be changed. This is my test code from your given, the output shape is `(14, 14, 32)`, maybe something wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./MNIST_data/', one_hot=True)

conv1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,28,28,32])
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2,2], strides=2)
print pool1.get_shape()
```

the output is:

```
Extracting ./MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting ./MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting ./MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting ./MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
(?, 14, 14, 32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the documentation is wrong then, i.e. has typo?

Answer (score 1):

Nikola, it has been corrected as you thought.

- [Documentation fixes for TF Layers tutorial (see #8301)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/863048121dc594acee3bcd869ab6dfef3109ce93#diff-0658a52cb38bc17b6237c313a69746c8)
- [Feedback on "A Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network" tutorial #8301](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8301)

Learning the concept of convolution and pooling, I come across this thread. Thank you for your question, which takes me to the informative documentation.